# How to make the points look larger in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data_exp, aes(x = transaction, y = exp, size = count, colour = class, label = label)) +
geom_point(alpha = 0.5) + 
geom_text(colour = "black", vjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.5, size = 3, fontface = "bold")
```

I want to make the points in the plot look larger, I try to make size becomes count*1000, but nothing seems to change.

[image: plot]

Comment: Try adding `+ scale_size(range=c(3, 10))` to your plot.

Comment: thank you! it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `size` aesthetic in `geom_point`

An example;

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
# increase point size based on variable value
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt,mpg))
p + geom_point(aes(size=wt*100))
```

[image]

Comment: Multiplying by a constant doesn't change the size range of the points. I guess because ggplot scales everything to the default size range.